# RSpec gives error 'trait not registered: name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I tried to test my Rails 3 application on Windows with RSpec. I've wrote tests and factories, but can't solve the issues which raise when I run RSpec on command line.

Here is one of the test files:
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "SignIns" do
  it "can sign in" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "login", with: user.username
    fill_in "password", with: user.password
    click_on "sign in"
    current_user.username.should == user.username
  end
end
```

And here's the factories.rb:

```
factory :layout do
  name "layout1"
end

factory :club do
  sequence(:name) { |i| "Club #{i}" }
  contact_name "John Doe"
  phone "+358401231234"
  email "#{name}@example.com"
  association :layout
end

factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |i| "user#{i}" }
  password 'password'
  email "test@example.com"
  club
end
```

When I try to run RSpec it gives the following error:

```
trait not registered: name
  #C: in 'object'
  #.spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb:11:in 'block (2 levels) in (top(required))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else ends up here when searching "Trait not registered":

When using a dependent attribute like how `email` depends on `name` in the `:club` factory from the question, you need to wrap the attribute in curly braces so it gets lazy evaluated:

```
email {"#{name}@example.com"}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a FactoryGirl error, and it seems you're using (at spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb:11) something like :

```
FactoryGirl.create :user, :name
```

This will only work if you registered a trait called name for the Factory `user`, more on traits [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/23673635798/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits)

Note that if you just want to override the name of the created user, the syntax is

```
FactoryGirl.create :user, name: 'THE NAME'
```

Comment: I've read about traits, but the line 11 is the call I have pasted above. So I can't still see the error? 

Writing the factories for my project is quite hard, because of the default scoping of every model to filter the correct club so I think the problem is in relations?

Comment: The `Club` factory requires a `:name` attribute -- does it have one?

Comment: Yeah, it has name field and so does layout have.

Answer (score 4):

For future readers' reference:

What didn't work -
**ArgumentError:
Trait not registered: user_id**

```
    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :startup do
        user_id
        name { FFaker::Lorem.word }
        website { FFaker::Internet.uri(host: 'example.com') }
        founded_at { "01.01.2000" }
      end
    end
```

How I solved this issue using either of these,  when everything seemed to look right:

1. put empty curly braces after user_id

```
    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :startup do
        user_id {}
        name { FFaker::Lorem.word }
        website { FFaker::Internet.uri(host: 'example.com') }
        founded_at { "01.01.2000" }
      end
    end
```

2. Move user_id below other block-using helpers:

```
    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :startup do
        name { FFaker::Lorem.word }
        website { FFaker::Internet.uri(host: 'example.com') }
        founded_at { "01.01.2000" }

        user_id
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another late answer. I banged my head awhile because I forgot my model is very new and I didn't migrate the `test` database. So the attribute in fact did not exist.

i.e. had to run beforehand

```sh
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the above(below?) answers helped to solve `trait not registered` error.

This time it was caused by **improper order of loading factories**. I've moved a file with declared global traits and FactoryBot started to load it in an improper order.

How did I fix it?
Rename it as, "spec/factories/01_factory_traits" and the issue is solved.

Perhaps there is a better way but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem that was due to us assigning attributes to a function that was not loaded yet. We got the trait not registered error and turns out it was due to the order in which factorybot would search when the attribute definition is ambiguous.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/5.1.1/FactoryBot/DefinitionProxy:method_missing