# FactoryGirl with a product model : Rspec tell me that "Trait not registered"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Hi magical community !

Still a newbie with basic question for those who have time ;-)

I created a User model and a Product model like this (thanks to @grotori):

```rb
class User
  has_many :owned_products, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  has_many :borrowed_products, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
end

class Product
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
    belongs_to :borrower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
end
```

Then I used FactoryGirl to create a factories.rb like this :

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "Person_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "kaboum"
    password_confirmation "kaboum"
  end

  factory :product do
    name "Product"
    owner
    borrower
  end
end
```

In order to test the `dependent: :destroy` condition like this :

```rb
describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User",
                        email: "user@example.com",
                        password: "kaboum",
                        password_confirmation: "kaboum")
  end

  describe "product associations" do
    before { @user.save }
    let!(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product, owner: @user) }

    it "should destroy associated product" do
      product_to_be_destroyed = @user.owned_products.first
      @user.destroy
      expect(product_to_be_destroyed).not_to be_empty
      expect(Product.where(id: product_to_be_destroyed.id)).to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec give me the answer `ArgumentError: Trait not registered: owner`.

I searched [already answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188273/rspec-gives-error-trait-not-registered-name) on stackoverflow but I couldn't fix my problem. One solution would be to assign a default value to my "owner" or "borrower" fields in my factories.rb, but I don't want that, which is possible accordingly to the [FactoryGirl help](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

Any help will be gratefully received :-)

Comment: Have you defined the factories `owner` and `borrower` with class `User`?

Comment: I just added the User factories...

Comment: I take it that you defined them as `factory :owner, :class => "User" do..`. Also, please go through the answer pointed out below by Billy Chan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said @kiddorails, I just had to add specific factories for my owners and borrowers. And here it comes (slightly different in the user_spec.rb part):

**spec/factories.rb**

```rb
  factory :owner, :class => "User" do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Owner #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "owner_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "kaboum"
    password_confirmation "kaboum"
  end

   factory :borrower, :class => "User" do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Borrower #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "borrower_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "kaboum"
    password_confirmation "kaboum"
  end

  factory :product do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Product #{n}" }
    owner
    borrower
  end
```

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```rb
  describe "product associations" do
    before { @user.save }
    let!(:product) { @user.owned_products.create(name:"tabouret") }

    it "should destroy the associated products" do
      product_id = @user.owned_products.first.id
      @user.destroy
      expect(product_id).not_to be_nil
      expect(Product.where(id: product_id)).to be_empty
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this could be solved without creating additional owner and borrower factories:

```
  factory :product do
    name "Product"
    association :owner, factory: :user
    association :borrower, factory: user
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the association relationship is wrong. No need to waste time on debugging FactoryGirl before correct models.

In common sense, a product can be borrowed or purchased by many users. And a user can borrow or purchase many products. How come the relationship is has_many and belongs_to?

Maybe modelling like this would be better

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :borrrow_records
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class BorrowRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end      

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: orders
  has_many: borrow_records
end
```

Comment: I don't see why my association relationship is wrong. A User can be Borrower and Owner, and a can have as many products as he wants. In the other hand, a Product can have only one Owner, and only one Borrower...

Comment: @FloRahl, if each piece of the product is unique, your model should be fine with a bit corrections. If they are common products, I don't think they can apply.

Comment: Each product is unique, because they are added and named by the users. I will later add category to sort them. Can you help me with a bit corrections ?

Comment: @FloRahl, I got it, a similar example is an used games market. But don't you still need Order and BorrowRecord model to store borrow or purchase transactions?

Comment: If borrowing, the product can be returned, and be available to borrow again. So a product may have several borrow records, each record has different User and borrower. Think about that.

Comment: OK, it's an history thing. Can we talk about it via private message ? Stackoverflow doesn't like too much comments...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29973/discussion-between-flo-rahl-and-billy-chan)